# Why did I need to use this statement twice - Matrix Multiplication

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix-multiplication

I was developing a program to find matrix multiplication.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0,e=0;
    cout<<"Enter the order of the first matrix  A  \n\nNumber of Rows : ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"\nNumber of Columns : ";
    cin>>b;
    cout<<endl;
    int matrixA[a][b];
    cout<<"Enter the matrix Elements "<<endl;
    for(int m=0; m<a; m++)
    {

        for(int n=0; n<b; n++)
        {
            cout<<"A ("<< m+1 <<" , "<<n+1<<" ) =";
            cin>>matrixA[m][n];
            //cout<<",";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

//////////////////////////  Startup

    cout<<"Enter the order of the Second matrix  A  \n\nNumber of Rows : "<<b;
    c=b;
    cout<<"\nNumber of Columns : ";
    cin>>d;
    cout<<endl;
    int matrixB[c][d];
    cout<<"Enter the matrix Elements "<<endl;
    for(int p=0; p<c; p++)
    {
        for(int q=0; q<d; q++)
        {
            cout<<"B ("<< p+1 <<" , "<<q+1<<" ) =";
            cin>>matrixB[p][q];
            //cout<<",";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    ///////////// initialisting matrixAns
    int matrixAns[a][d];

    for(int p=0; p<a; p++)
    {
        for(int q=0; q<d; q++)
        {
            matrixAns[p][q]=0;    
        }    
    }

////////////////////  finding ans
    for(int r=0; r<a; r++)
    {
        for(int s=0; s<d; s++)
        {
            for(int t=0; t<b; t++)
            {    
                e = matrixA[r][t]*matrixB[t][s];       
            }
            matrixAns[r][s] = e+matrixAns[r][s];
            matrixAns[r][s] = e+matrixAns[r][s];   //dont know why i have to add this same code again
    }
    }

////////////////////// Ans Printing    
    cout<<"\nMatrix Multiplication Answer  \n"<<endl;
    for(int h=0; h<a; h++)
    {    
        for(int i=0; i<d; i++)
        {    
            cout<<" "<<matrixAns[h][i]<<" ";    
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }    
}
```

And one important thing: this is not my homework or assignment!

The method that I have used  works perfectly but it does not give me the right answer until I use this statement twice. (I got  this by a trial and error method).

```
matrixAns[r][s] = e+matrixAns[r][s];
```

I have also initailised the `matrixAns` by using a loop (and had set it to 0).

I am new to C++ and want to know what was the error that I got and how the use of the two statements gives me correct answer.

Is there any way to get rid of one of the statements without destroying the app?

Comment: If you write it twice, it is equivalent to `matrixAns[r][s] = 2*e+matrixAns[r][s]`. is this want you want?

Comment: I want to know how you got C++ to make arrays of non-constant values.

Comment: This is more flexible as it can find the multiple of any matrix that satisfies the basic condition!

Comment: @mikeTheLiar That's a g++ extension that's enabled by default unfortunately.

Comment: Incidentally, most programmers would use `matrixAns[r][s] += e;`

Comment: A few observations: you're only getting the correct answer for very few matrices (so try some more & debug your code) & you're overwriting the value of `e` in the `for(int t=0; t<b; t++)` loop before adding it to `matrixAns[r][s]` (which is probably not what you want).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not doing the dot products correctly when calculating your answer. You need to multiply individual cells between the two matrices, then sum **all** those products for an individual cell in your answer.

Your code is only taking the product, in `e`, of the *last* multiplication - `matrix[r][b - 1] * matrixB[b - 1][s]` -  and discarding the first *N-1* products. Adding `e` - this last multiplication - once, or twice or 3 times are all incorrect, though it may *appear* to work with certain inputs.

Your answer loop, with comments:

```
for(int r=0; r<a; r++)
{
    for(int s=0; s<d; s++)
    {
        for(int t=0; t<b; t++)
        {
            e = matrixA[r][t]*matrixB[t][s];
        }

        // now e only has the value from that final multiplication, of
        //    matrix[r][b - 1] * matrixB[b - 1][s]. All of the other
        //    products were lost.

        // so now it doesn't matter how many times you add e, you'll
        //    get the wrong product:
        matrixAns[r][s] = e+matrixAns[r][s];
        matrixAns[r][s] = e+matrixAns[r][s];
    }
}
```

Change your answer loop to:

```
for(int r=0; r<a; r++)
{
    for(int s=0; s<d; s++)
    {
        for(int t=0; t<b; t++)
        {
            e = matrixA[r][t]*matrixB[t][s];

            // accumulation of the products should be INSIDE the loop:
            matrixAns[r][s] = matrixAns[r][s] + e;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you printed matrixAns[r][s] to make sure it holds something?

It sounds like matrixAns[r][s] is empty; this is what I think is happening:

```
matrixAns[r][s] = e+matrixAns[r][s]; //stores e in matrixAns[r][s]
matrixAns[r][s] = e+matrixAns[r][s]; //adds e to e (whats in matrixAns[r][s])
```

Comment: if he is getting the correct multiplication answer, then it isnt possible.

Comment: perhaps. what is the point of
for(int t=0; t<b; t++)
{
    e = matrixA[r][t]*matrixB[t][s];
}

why not just use the final cells to store e?

Comment: I have added a comment for the place where i have initialised this matrixAns .. hum anyway it is holding the initail value!

Comment: @abhejit.rajagopal it is used to initialise the matrix !